# Whats wrong with my Excel conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to mark a column's data with a red background if the values in it are outside of a 15% threshold. For this I'm trying to use the formula:

`=(ABS(($D:$D-$E:$E)/$E:$E))>0.15`

However, it won't change the background (even after I click OK on the conditional formatting windows to apply the formatting):

[image]

What am I missign here?

Comment: If you write `(ABS(($D:$D-$E:$E)/$E:$E))`in a cell, does it give you a value, or error? I bet your problem is with how you refer to the current value. You should make a selection, then look to where your cursor is. In your Case that's D1. So you would program your formula as: D1-E1/E1. The cells will automatically transpose correctly over the cells.

Comment: No errors... If I do `=$F1>0.15` it works, but if I do `=$F:$F>0.15` it doesn't. The issue is, I want to generate these rules via code, and I'd need a way to simply apply it to a whole columns, instead of applying it to each cell individually.

Comment: You can't apply it to whole columns. If you want to do it via code, press record macro, select whole column, do conditional formatting that works, for example =$F1>0.15 and stop recording. Then inspect how Excel generates the code and use that. Its likely they just select the range and set $f1>0.15, just like you manually do.

Comment: Yeah it actually gets generalised to the whole column automatically. Weird for my logic but ok... :D

Comment: I've written you an answer, given that its likely that our comment exchange lead to the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to calculate the percentage for the entire column at once.

Use:

```
=(ABS(($D1:$D1-$E1:$E1)/$E1:$E1))>0.15
```

Then apply it to the range you want the conditional formatting to apply to

Answer (score 0):

The reason this goes wrong is because you apply the formula to the entire column, rather to the first cell in the column.

Excel will automatically set the other cells correctly.

Given that you want to use this in VBA code, I recommend pressing the record button, then manually execute the conditional formatting setup, then stop the recording and see what Excel generates as VBA code.

I suspect it simply does

```
range(D:D).select
'code for setting up conditional formatting and using (ABS((D1-E1)/E1))>0.15 as formula
```

Excel automatically sets the other cells, so you don't need to use columns. Otherwise, it would literally try to calculate all the percentages at once, and if it happens to be in >0.15 then all cells would color red.

Comment: I'm using it with Python and xlsxwriter. Choosing the first cell made Excel generalise it OK. A bit weird for my logic, but hey, it's Excel, barely anything makes sense ever :D